# Know REST calls of a mobile app

Tags: android, api, rest, mobile

I am trying to know the REST call of a mobile application what I use. I am developing an application and I need to do the same call / get the same result of the mobile application what I downloaded.

I would like to do call the same API.

Does it possible to catch this kind of information ?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to sniff API calls. See [more details](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2014/06/sniffing-http-traffic-on-an-android-device.html)